# copy files on secondary drives by shh

Tags: networking, transfer

From a newbie

I have 2 computers on a router network.

I eventually got the machines networked using SSH connection. (figured out I had to disable VPN service first)

Machine 1 has one 250GB SSD(call it SSD1) and one 2TB HDD(call it HDD1).
Machine 2 has one 250GB SSD(call it SSD2) and one 2TB HDD(call it HDD2)

Each machine uses the SSD for  dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 + Win 10 operating systems.
Each machine uses their HDD for mass storage.

So it is a very simple symetrical system.

How can I transfer large files from HDD2 to HDD1(Both SSDs are getting full)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PC you're using to the other one run:

```
scp <path_to_the_file> username_of_the_other_PC@IP_address_of_the_other_PC:<path_where_you_want_to_copy_the_file>
```

EXP:

```
scp ~/folder_1/filename.mp4 second_pc@192.168.1.50:~/hdd_2/folder_2/
```